# Unable to attach Amazon SQS to Amazon S3 event notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-sqs

I have 2 different buckets.
One is able to attach Amazon SQS to event notification and the second doesn't.

SQS permissions is broad enough. It's smth with S3 bucket. But I can't figure it out.

There are no "Deny" clauses in bucket policy.
There are several additional ACL though...

This is my Access Policy stored in SQS:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the error:
[image]

Comment: Have you already created the SQS queue?

Comment: Yep. There are no other options.

Comment: What is inside API response? What is the SQS permissions?

Comment: SQS permission in my question. 
API response is empty(it's opened on the screenshot).

Comment: What do you mean by "This is my policy for SQS" -- is it the **Access Policy** stored on the SQS Queue?

Comment: Yep. Thank you. Edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted AWS Support. There provided undocumented details:

> So, each time an S3 event is edited or saved, there will be validation
> of the current destinations since the PutBucketNotification will
> replace the existing notification configuration and not update it.

So I had another legacy S3 event that didn't have correct permissions. I removed it, and everything is working right now. Thank you to all who tried to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have seen this before.

You must **create an Access Policy on the Amazon SQS queue** to permit access by the Amazon S3 bucket.

Here is a sample policy from [Granting permissions to publish event notification messages to a destination - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3.html):

```json
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Id": "example-ID",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
     "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"  
   },
   "Action": [
    "SQS:SendMessage"
   ],
   "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:Region:account-id:queue-name",
   "Condition": {
      "ArnLike": { "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:awsexamplebucket1" },
      "StringEquals": { "aws:SourceAccount": "bucket-owner-account-id" }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

See also: [Walkthrough: Configuring a bucket for notifications (SNS topic or SQS queue) - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html)

Comment: It works for one bucket but not for the other.